# How to make input only accept a-z etc

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm having trouble getting my input to accept only a-z and A-Z letters. This is what I came up with

```
        while(not(studentName == "END")):
    studentName = input("What is the name of the student (END to finish) ")
    if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", studentName):
        print("Only letters are allowed")
    elif len(studentName) == 0:
        print("Insufficient characters. Please try again.")
    else:
        studentsNames.append(studentname)
```

However I just come up with an error "re not defined".
What do I do :C

Comment: so you should `import re`

Comment: import re before using re

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using regular expressions, I like to use the built-in string methods. One of these is `str.isalpha()`, which, when called on a string, returns `True` if the string contains *only* `A-z`. So instead of:

```
if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", studentName):
    print("Only letters are allowed")
```

I'd just write:

```
if not studentName.isalpha():
    print("Only letters are allowed!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `re` module and you must need to change your regex as,

```
if not re.match(r"^[A-Za-z]+$", studentName):
```

Just type the below code at the top of your python script.

```
import re
```

Your regex `"^[a-z]*$"` would match zero or more lowercase letters. That is, it would match empty strings also and it won't match the string with only uppercase letters like `FOO`.

So this `if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", studentName):` will return `true` for all the strings which must not be an empty string or the string which contains only lowercase letters.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the help but I'm kinda new to this (sorry), what do you mean to import my re and to change my regex?

Comment: you need to change the if not line like above.

Comment: Sorry to be a burden, but is there anyway you could explain in one sentence what I'm doing when I'm importing "re", I don't like doing things without understand them ahah... sorry :C

Comment: First you have to install it using pip install then you can import it

Comment: @VigneshKalai it's an inbuilt module.

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry forgot :p

Comment: Just read that explanation you gave, thank you guys so much you geniuses <3

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), and [string.ascii_letters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters):

```
from string import ascii_letters

def is_all_characters(student_name):
    return set(student_name) in set(ascii_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

isalpha() works for this requirement.

```
username = input("Enter Username: ")
if username.isalpha() is False:
 print("Only Text allowed in Username")
else:
 print("Welcome "+username)
```

Answer (score -2):

while True:
while True:
studentName = input("What is the name of the student: ")
if studentName.isalpha():
print("welcome to the cse ", studentName)
break
else:
print("Invalid input")
break